# SSD showing in DiskManagement but not in Window Explorer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have got a new SSD ([Corsair Force Series 3 120 GB SSD Internal Hard Drive](http://www.flipkart.com/corsair-force-series-3-120-gb-ssd-internal-hard-drive-cssd-f120gb3a-bk/p/itmd5cmgxryjqg7k?pid=IHDD5CMHGK84EC8T)) . I am trying to connect it using SATA to USB . Window is detecting the drive but not mounting it!!

When I am trying to check in the DiskManagement it appears as unallocated space in Disk1 but Unable to create New volume is this option is disabled[image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the disk.  See the red down arrow on the left by Disk 1 in the Disk Manamement Window?  Right click that area to initialize the disk.  Once that is done, you can create a new volume.